# NSIS get path of current installer file that is running

Tags: installation, nsis

Is there an NSIS var to get the path of the currently running installer?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Found it: $EXEPATH

Answer (score 15):

There are few useful variables:

- `$EXEPATH` - holds installer filename.
- `$EXEDIR` - holds the complete path to the installer.

So according to the topic

> NSIS get **path** of current installer file that is running

the most appropriate is `$EXEDIR`.

Comment: $EXEPATH is the complete path to the installer including the filename. $EXEDIR is only the directory where the the installer file resides. $EXEFILE is the base filename of the installer name, e.g. "myinstaller.exe"